# Java SE Application hanging - could the cause be an Error (e.g. OutOfMemoryError)?

Tags: java, performance

We have a Java SE application that occasionally hangs, without any reason.

At the moment, as I understand is best practice, I catch, log and display a message for `Exception`s but not `Error`s. Obviously, when the application hangs (and never returns) there is no way for me to find out what went wrong - and crucially, no error message displayed.

Does this sound like an `Error` is being thrown? I've turned on logging with `log4j`, but I'm unsure whether this will even give any detail if such an error is thrown

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's very hard to tell without any context - we have no indication *whatsoever* what kind of application this is, other than "Java SE". It's also not clear how performance is involved.

Comment: It's a thick client Java SE 1.6 application.. The application has multiple users, and only a few get this problem each day (and only once per day). Does that help?

Comment: As a general rule, as you do not catch an `Error` it should bubble all the way up the stack, out of the `main` method and cause the process to terminate with an error.  However if you're using any sort of framework (e.g. webapp, Spring launching the app) this may catch the error somewhere and do whatever it wants with it...

Comment: Do yourself a big favor: stop listening to the dubious "best practice" and log all `Throwable`s at the top of your call stack. If you worry about the consistency of your app, you can still panic and quit in case the caught throwable is something you are really afraid of. BTW in many years of production I have never found the "panic mode" necessary.

Comment: I do use Spring as an IOC container, but the JVM is started directly using the command line rather than through Spring as such. If I'm following - an Error would therefore produce an error message displayed to the user, and termination of the application, rather than the symptom of hanging that I'm currently seeing?

Comment: @user2482461: Swing? SWT? Something else? Note that the process will only terminate if the last non-daemon thread exits - if you've got an error in a background thread, that will be written to the console but not do anything to the process.

Comment: I use Swing for the front-end.. Could it be that the EDT is throwing this error but the main application thread is still running?

Comment: @JonSkeet - if this is indeed occurring, I assume that log4j will also log the error (even if nothing is done to the process itself)?

Comment: No, log4j wouldn't get any kind of "hook" to log it, unless you were calling log4j yourself.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Ok - thank you - I think the next course of action will be to change the exception handler to take all `Throwable` objects and log it there. Thanks!

Comment: Lot of strange suggestions in the comments... just do a thread-dump (use `jstack`) and check which thread is blocked and why. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/hangloop-140257.html

Comment: @PavelHoral: Yes, I also believe that a deadlock is more probably than anything else.

Comment: @maaartinus But there's only one synchronized method in the whole app.. It's not a very multi-threaded app at all..

Comment: This surely lowers the probability, but still... a single deadlock suffices and it needs just two locks and two threads (and there's the AWT thread there). Or maybe you're waiting on some never to happen IO. Anyway, a thread dump could show.